# Music from SD card is not visible unless it's copied via cable connection to the phone

Tags: 8.0, lumia, music, sd-card

I'm using Lumia 520, and I have an SDHC card.

I've noticed a strange thing. I managed to see the music in the built-in Music app after copying my MP3s to `[SDcard]/Music` (or a subfolder), but only if I put the files there when the phone was on. The files that were already there (I used the SD card with my previous phone), are not visible (though they're visible also in my Win XP normally). Though the videos on the contrary are displayed in the Videos app.

Has someone experienced that? Is there some easier way than to delete files and copy them again?

Comment: Did you check for replica of those files in phone memory?

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed that even if you copied it to the SD card like that, you can manually move one (or more) of the songs in the phone memory with a file manager – they will show up in the XBox Music app – and using the app you will move the files back to the SD card. Not the best solution but it's *A* solution.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, what you're noticing is exactly how it's designed to work.

Copying files over the cable somehow makes the phone register their existence. Doing it any other way, does not.

This also applies to ringtones: you can't use the phone to copy an .mp3 file from the music folder to the ringtones folder: the file will copy over, but the phone won't know it's there, and it won't appear in the list of available ringtones to choose from. You have to copy the .mp3 into the ringtones folder from your computer.

So, to get your phone to register the existence of the music, upload it to the phone's music folder from a connected computer.

Comment: This clearly sucks. On my old Sony phone, it scans for music when it's booted or disconnected from the cable. Anyway I'm struggling now to copy any files to the SD card actually (when trying doing it via phone), since it just hangs and doesn't copy anything. I'm using XP, I'll have to try from Windows 7... Copying to the SD card directly works perfectly, but the phone won't see the files as I mentioned.

Comment: This doesn't clearly suck. By not doing what your old phone did, it saves you time on booting your phone. In most cases you get philes on your phone that you received either through cable or downloaded from internet.

I understand this to be annoying. And maybe if you rename the directory your files are in, it might re-index your files in that folder, because all filepaths need to be changed.